# Why is ejecting a create-react-app app a one way operation?

Tags: npm, create-react-app

> Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back! … At this point you’re on your own.

Claims the CRA docs. However, I don't see why this is. If I am using a VCS, what is preventing me from rolling back the changes made by running `npm run eject`? This would imply there's something outside the project that affects it, which violates some vague notions about principles of modern web dev that I have in my head..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can revert** `eject` if you revert the changes in VCS.

`eject` will just copy configuration files to your working directory so that you have edit them the way you want.

Keep in mind that once you eject, there could be changes in structure in `node_modules` as scripts will be looking in different paths. Also, `node_modules` are generally *not tracked* in version management systems. So after you revert the `eject`, you might have to install dependencies with `npm install` or `yarn`

If that doesn't work, try removing `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` or `yarn` again.

Basically, everything that is tracked in version management systems can be reverted back.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think a picture begins to explain it. It appears to compile somewhat your app and package.json. Although my node_modules folder appears to get bigger, if I deleted it and type yarn it comes back but only 29 MB this time instead of the larger 175 MB you can see in the screenshot prior to this.

```
➜  aminosee copy git:(master) ✗ yarn
yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning " > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 68.43s.
```

[image]

[image]